# Custom shape div blocks

Tags: html, background, shapes

Prompt in what direction to think.
What tool can be used to create such an image shape?
Please note the different sizes of the bottom section of the image depending on the content.
[image]

Comment: with [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS), you can do it. using pseudoelements like `::before` and `::after`

Comment: How to set an angle of 45 degrees and at the same time a semicircle?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Look into `clip-path`!

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal and not good solution, but something like this

```css
body {
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
}


span {
  top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background-color: #90a8c1;
  border-radius: 16px;
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button-container {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #dfdfdf;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
}


.button-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 0.2px solid #dfdfdf;
  color: #000;
  background: #d29038;
  padding: 6px;
  border-radius: 26px;
  top: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.button-container::before {
  content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    width: 20px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
    box-shadow: -10px 0 0 0 #dfdfdf;
}

.button-container::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    bottom: -6px;
    right: -40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transform: rotate(23deg);
    border-bottom: 7px solid #dfdfdf;
}
 
.text::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 28px solid transparent;
    border-left: 32px solid #dfdfdf;
    top: -7px;
    right: -29px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="button-container">
    <a>Click</a>
    <span class="text">Someone text</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="button-container">
    <a>Click</a>
    <span class="text">Someone</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why so complicated instead of simply using clip-path?

Comment: Clip-path hard to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

We take svg corners and through absolute positioning we attach to the usual square div. This is what the corners look like

[image]